# Change host of all links on page with js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, uri

There is a website example.com. I want to change all links on that website so they appear to different host. I need to change these types of links:

```
  <a href="page.html?attr=1">Link</a>
  <a href="example.com/page2.html?attr=1">Link</a>
  <a href="subdomain.example.com/page3.html?attr=1">Link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="mirror.com/page.html?attr=1">Link</a>
<a href="mirror.com/page2.html?attr=1">Link</a>
<a href="subdomain.mirror.com/page3.html?attr=1">Link</a>
```

While leaving form and js urls as is. I wonder what is the less painful way to do that? I know that parsing urls with regex is bad, so how can I parse these urls as a class and do operations to them?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var $me = $(this);
    var url = $me.attr('href');
    var newUrl = url.replace('example','mirror');
    if(newUrl.indexOf('mirror') < 0) newUrl = 'mirror.com/' + url;
    $me.attr('href',newUrl);
})
```

this will change all the `<a>` and only them (no forms and script href)